# Sheetjs detect and remove headers

Tags: xlsx, sheetjs

I have an app that handles different xlsx sheets
I need to a method that clear all header if exists

I tried this way to get the header range but thats not correct

```
  var columnCount = xlsx.utils.decode_range(workSheet["!ref"]).e.c + 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
      header[i] = workSheet[`${xlsx.utils.encode_col(i)}1`].v;
    }
```

is there an easier way to remove the header, here how its looks like

**more details**
the goal of the question is to detect where is the sheet table is stared to sip the header in that case `6` index will do the trick for me

```
xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, {
      raw: false,
      range: 6, ---> sheet index 
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific re *clear all header if exists* - what would it mean in terms of the Excel spreadsheet ?

Comment: I mean I need to find the index of sheet table to skip the header and convert the sheet to jason

Comment: Is your question specific to Excel pivot tables ?

Comment: yes exactly I need to extract data from pivot table after remove header